# Alexa unable to fetch results from a site

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have two doubts regarding **lambda function**.

I'm trying to make a *Alexa skill*, which fetches some data from [this](http://contesttrackerapi.herokuapp.com/) site, and does some operations based on the request of the user.

1. Now my *lambda function* is working properly on my machine (If I comment out some lines) and display the data properly. However, the lambda function doesn't seem to wait for the `request` to get completed on the *aws server*, (because I can't see the **log** inside my function printed in the logs on the server).

This is the code I used to get the data from the site:

```
console.log("Initiating request");
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function(error, response, body){
    console.log("Request send, waiting to load the data..."); // Not executed
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log("Data obtained :: ");
        data = body;
        console.log(data.toString());
        });
    }
    else{
        console.log("Error: " + error.message); 
    }
});
```

[Here](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/Alexa-Contest-Tracker) is the complete code for any further reference.

This is the log output of the execution:

> START RequestId: 621ee488-f187-11e7-b063-99e0641d97b4 Version: $LATEST
>   2018-01-04T19:42:23.742Z  621ee488-f187-11e7-b063-99e0641d97b4    GetNewContestIntent
>   2018-01-04T19:42:23.778Z  621ee488-f187-11e7-b063-99e0641d97b4    Data
>   given by the user :  undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined
>   2018-01-04T19:42:23.798Z  621ee488-f187-11e7-b063-99e0641d97b4    Hello
>   2018-01-04T19:42:26.419Z  621ee488-f187-11e7-b063-99e0641d97b4    Initiating
>   request
>   2018-01-04T19:42:26.481Z  621ee488-f187-11e7-b063-99e0641d97b4    Here are
>   some contests:  END RequestId: 621ee488-f187-11e7-b063-99e0641d97b4
>   REPORT RequestId: 621ee488-f187-11e7-b063-99e0641d97b4    Duration:
>   2808.73 ms    Billed Duration: 2900 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 47 MB

(The undefined values are acceptable, I want them to be `"undefined"`).

The second one is weird, I don't know why it happened to me.

2. I had to do a `npm install request` in order to get my `request` function running, and had to upload the zip file of my lambda function and sdk. But because of this, I'm unable to edit my code using the **Edit code Inline** option. It doesn't show anything if I select the option. Although I can see the editor for my other functions. This is not a real issue, but I had to upload complete code every time I make any changes in my code, which is troublesome.

Can anyone help me with these issues? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general the problem is that you are making alexa respond `this.emit(':responseReady');` before the request is finished, this is because in this section of your code you invoke `request` which execute the request, but the `function` you define there to process the response would be executed async, so before that the program will continue with the next command after request `if(invalidRequest)` and so on until reaching alexa's response a few lines later.

   ```
   console.log("Initiating request");
   request({
       url: url,
       json: true
   }, function(error, response, body){
       console.log("Request send, waiting to load the data...");
       ...
   });

   if(invalidRequest){
       speechOutput = errorMessage;
   }else{
       speechOutput = GET_CONTEST_MESSAGE + ans;
   }

   console.log(speechOutput);
   this.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME, speechOutput);
   this.response.speak(speechOutput);
   this.emit(':responseReady');
   ```

This could be fixed in two ways. If your alexa's answer **needs** the data from the request, then you should emit the response the callback function for your request. [Here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/29) are some examples of this implementation.

The other option would be if you answer doesn't necessarily needs the data, maybe you ask alexa to process the data and she will just say that the data is being processed. For this scenario I would have the request and data processing in a different lambda function and your `intent` would invoke this other lambda which will run on its own. [Here](https://blog.hellojs.org/3-common-challenges-using-javascript-node-js-in-aws-lambda-e3fc318401ba) is a text that could help you to invoke one lambda from another and to understand a little better on how this problem happened.

2. I have had the same problem but haven't been able to find an official explination, though the main reason seems to be the zip size; in some forums people talk about a max limit for editing of 51,200 bytes but I wasn't able to find an official argument for that, instead I have uploaded zips up to 1mb and still being able to edit the files inside, but I also have some other zips up to 6mb and there I couldn't edit anything.

You could also look for tools to facilitate uploading you code to lambda, the one I'm using is [Serverless](https://serverless.com/)

Comment: I understood what you said, and I put that part of the code in another function and called that function from within the `request` function. And now I am getting a `time out error` (**Task timed out after 3.00 seconds**). Can you give me any inputs on that?

Comment: how are you invoking the second lambda? and is at least the second lambda working properly? I guess it could be on how you are invoking the lambda, for default it is called as sync method but you can specify it as async. in the invocation `lambda.invoke(params, some_callback)` `params` should have property `InvocationType: "Event"`

Comment: I'm not invoking any second lambda, its just one lambda function that does all the job. And my `ans` needs the data received from the `request`.

Comment: ok, maybe the request needs more than 3 seconds, you could try increasing that in your lambda configuration. Is any log from the `request`'s response? Once I had an error in a lambda (nothing to do with alexa) where I had a connection to a database but I didn't close it so I was always getting the same **Task timed out after 3.00 seconds**. If you update your code I could give it a look

Comment: There were some log from the `request`'s response, but they appear only sometimes, majorly there was nothing. And, please take a look, I've updated some of my code, (but it still doesn't work. I was trying to use `directiveServiceCall` from [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/master/handling-responses/dialog-directive-delegate/step-by-step/2-lambda-function.md) . Thank you for your time, I had given up on this. Please help me out. [Here](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/Alexa-Contest-Tracker) is my code on github.

Comment: And please tell me how to increase the **timeout** in lambda. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443602/alexa-skills-set-sdk-increase-timeout-of-skill) link and also set the `shouldEndSession` to false, but nothing worked out, so I removed it.

Comment: in the aws console got to Lambda en select your lambda function, there you would see different sections like _Designer_, _Function code_, and more, in the section _Basic settings_ there is the timeout setting with a field for minutes and another field for seconds, change the values for how long you want the lambda function to run until a timeout. 
This is the time for alexa to prepare her answer; in the link you mentioned, they wanted to increase the time alexa waits for the user response

Comment: Thank you it helped. I increased the **timeout**, and used `request`.