# Alexa sdk, save data for later sessions

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm relatively new to Alexa and AWS. I'm trying to save data generated by a RequestHandler to use it later in another Handler. I know how to use the SessionAttributes, but this only works, if the skill isn't terminated meanwhile and since i can't increase the timeout, i need another solution. I read in another post, that you can save something in some DB, but i don't know how he did that:
[Alexa Skills Set SDK - increase timeout of skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443602/alexa-skills-set-sdk-increase-timeout-of-skill)
Can anyone recommend a tutorial or documentation for something like that?
Btw i use nodejs and sdk v2

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

If you are trying to save the data somewhere, like a database, it is better to use Dynamo DB.

Here's a [link](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/courses/cake-walk-5) to the tutorial on adding Memory to your skill. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: ok that looks promising, although if i understand it correctly, i can only read and write 25 times(each) per month for free. is there a cheaper way? i i only need to save 3 strings (no longer than 250 characters)

Comment: I think you are good to go. you are talking about 25 WCU - which is different than the amount of data you want to say - DynamoDB gives you 25 GB of data for free. Hope that helps.